# Find the CDF of a function of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> The joint probability density function of two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ is:
>
> $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 6x,& 0\leqslant x\leqslant y,\ 0\leqslant y\leqslant 1\\ 0,& \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
>
> Determine the CDF of $(X,Y)$.

I'm stuck at the beginning. I realize the CDF will be a piece-wise function and I need to determine the different intervals first.

From my reasoning, I should check the following intervals:

**1)** $x\leqslant0$ or $y\leqslant0$

**2)** $x \in (0,y]$ and $y \in (0,1]$

**3)** $x \in (0,y]$ and $y > 1$

**4)** $x > y$ and $y \in (0,1]$

**5)** $x > y$ and $y > 1$

However, I looked at the hint provided by my textbook and it says I should check the following intervals instead:

**1)** $x\leqslant0$ or $y\leqslant0$

**2)** $x \in (0,y]$ and $y \in (0,1]$

**3)** $x \in (0,1]$ and $y > 1$

**4)** $x > y$ and $y \in (0,1)$

**5)** $x > 1$ and $y > 1$

I'm having trouble making sense out of the last three intervals. How are these intervals determined?

Comment: the CDF is $1$ over the last three intervals :-)

Comment: Can't agree there.

Answer (score 0):

In any problem of this type, the first step is to draw a picture.
Your joint density function is only positive on the triangle labelled $2$,
 and the CDF $F(x,y)$ is the probability of being below and 
to the left of the point $(x,y)$.

[image]

The advantage of the textbook's scheme is that the formula for $F$ naturally 
breaks into easy cases. In region 1, you get $F(x,y)=0$ and in 
region 5, $F(x,y)=1$. In region 3 $F(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ only, 
while in region 4 it is a function of $y$ only.

Let's compare this with your scheme. First of all, you only differ 
in regions 3 and 5. In your region 5, we still have $F(x,y)=0$.
However in your region 3, we have $F(x,y)=1$ when $x\geq 1$ and 
$F(x,y)<1$ when $x<1$. It is possible to write a single formula
for $F$ in this region, but $x=1$ forms a natural breakpoint, so I 
guess this is why the textbook suggests it.

There is no right way or wrong way to divide the plane 
to get a multipart formula for $F$, but there are ways 
that are more convenient and less convenient.